# Localization make it possible to add language files after compile

Tags: localization, resx

I´m having a program that needs to be translated in many languages.
I want to release it and make it possible to add specific languages later on.

Let´s say i have app.setting where the user can set smomething like "de" or "en" or "ci".

Therefore it should just try to load the resx. file named [apllicationname].de.rsex
or [applicationname].ci.resx

When a user wants to have the app with the chinese language he only needs to add the ci file into a folder.

I hope you can understand what i want. I want the customer to be able to add specific language files afterwards.

Comment: There is no question...so what do you expect?

Comment: read title, nvm found solution myselfe